# Creating an enum from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to mimic the behavior of the "profile provider" that is available in .Net.  The profile provider acquires profile properties from the `web.config` and those properties are immediately available as an `enum` for use in the code behind.

I'm unsure how to do this, and wondered whether someone may be able to help.

Essentially I'd like to allow developers to enter `Role` information into the `web.config`, and then have this role information available for use within an `enum` in the codebehind.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to do is use *dynamic* enums?

If so, I think you might have to consider a different implementation - enums are defined at compile-time so what you want to do isn't going to be possible using them.

A similar question was asked before: [Dynamic enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/dynamic-enum-in-c) and *it can be done*, via buildproviders. But there might be another (simpler) way to achieve what you want to do ...

Comment: Yep, this was what I was after.  If anyone's curious, this article is quite helpful too.
[Custom Build Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/EXCustomBuildProviders.aspx)

Comment: That's a great article - I had avoided up till now due to the relative incomprehensibility (to me, anyway) of the MSDN documentation about this. Many thanks for sharing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but I think "build provider" is the word you're looking for...
http://www.google.no/search?q=build+provider+asp.net