# Generating DLL with two or more dynamic enums

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums

I followed this Q & A: [Dynamic enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/dynamic-enum-in-c-sharp)  and it works well, the best answer has code from this [msdn article: EnumBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder.aspx)

This Dynamic Enum code generation works for one Enum in the DLL. The problem is when I attempt to add a second Enum it doesn't work, I can only access the first Enum "Elevation" from the referenced DLL.

**How do I add two or more Enums to the DLL?**

```
class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the current application domain for the current thread.
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        // Create a dynamic assembly in the current application domain,  
        // and allow it to be executed and saved to disk.
        AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
        AssemblyBuilder ab = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        // Define a dynamic module in "TempAssembly" assembly. For a single-
        // module assembly, the module has the same name as the assembly.
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

        // Define a public enumeration with the name "Elevation" and an 
        // underlying type of Integer.
        EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("Elevation", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

        // Define two members, "High" and "Low".
        eb.DefineLiteral("Low", 0);
        eb.DefineLiteral("High", 1);

        // Create the type and save the assembly.
        Type finished = eb.CreateType();

        //-------------------------------------
        //HERE IS THE CODE TO CREATE A 2ND ENUM
        //-------------------------------------
        EnumBuilder eb1 = mb.DefineEnum("SecondEnum", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
        eb1.DefineLiteral("Bad", 0);
        eb1.DefineLiteral("Good", 1);
        Type SecondEnum = eb1.CreateType();

        ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your code. What is the problem?

Comment: @MårtenWikström Run the code and it will produce a DLL, then reference the generated DLL in another project and try and use the `SecondEnum`

Comment: I've done that. It works just as I would expect. You really need to describe what your problem is! Can you not see `SecondEnum`? Do you get a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: @MårtenWikström thanks for your help, this bare bones repro works for me too "at home".

Answer (score 1):

Something odd is happening at work because I can do it at home. Ref TempAssembly in another project and I can access the `SecondEnum`:

```
using ProjectName;
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(SecondEnum.Good.ToString());
}
```

**Update:**

Turns out I was adding two values (numbers), not a key and a value.

```
SecondEnum.DefineLiteral("Must Be Alphanumeric", Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()));
```

**Update 2:**

Make sure the Enum doesn't start with a space!!