# Dynamic ValueOf Type Enforcement

Tags: c#

I would like to define a value type which has a finite set of elements, which in turn are elements of a dynamically defined list at runtime (for example from a database).

With this, I would like to be able to enforce type safety (well, sort of) on a dynamic list without having any of the values available at compile time. I could then use the new type in my code for properties, as return values in methods etc.

(Note - it isn't really type-"safety", i.e. compile-time checking I am after, but rather the ability to conceptually identify "this type of value" in methods and properties - for better understandability and readability of the code.)

Pseudocode:

```
type Currency = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP"];
Currency cur = new Currency();
cur = "CAD";     // must throw an exception

Currency.Add("CAD");
cur = "CAD";     // now it would NOT throw an exception
```

It is a bit like a subclass of "String" but String is a sealed class and cannot be derived from.

You could also see it as a type defined as the return of a "ValueOf" function from a list. But this does not give me a way to define a type in C#.

Is there any reasonably sensible way to do what I want?

Comment: I think what you are looking for might be to use a struct

Comment: This seems like a very strange design.  You want a runtime list of values that are checked against when trying to assign properties value?

Comment: @mahlatse how would that help?

Comment: You could define a class and add an identifier string that will throw an exception when set to `"CAD"`

Comment: I  think the following link can help you ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/automatically-create-an-enum-based-on-values-in-a-database-lookup-table

Comment: Create a list of struct values at runtime that are linked to your specific DB data, then you can check against that list.

Comment: @mahlatse: I am trying to use a TYPE which can be used in property declarations and method return values. Certainly I can do as you say - I am looking for a more elegant way here

Comment: @Nirzar: That link sounds quite good (creating a dynamic assembly with generated enums)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that when you talk about Type Safety, most C# developers will automatically assume you're talking about compile-time checking. Since this isn't what you're asking, some people are getting put off.

What you're asking to do isn't really a language function, but it's something you can do with simple programming concepts:

```
void Main()
{
    Currency.Add("USD", "EUR", "GBP");
    Currency cur = new Currency("CAD"); // must throw an exception

    Currency.Add("CAD");
    cur = new Currency("CAD"); // now it would NOT throw an exception
}

public class Currency{
    private static List<string> availableValues = new List<string>();

    public static void Add(params string[] values){
    foreach (var value in values)
        {
            availableValues.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public Currency(string value){
        if(!availableValues.Contains(value)){
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value + " is not a valid Currency");
        }
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public string Value{get;}

    public override string ToString() => Value;
}
```

This code assumes you are going to register all the available currencies on startup. If you expect new values to be added while the class is actively being used, you'll want to use something like a `ConcurrentDictionary<>` instead of a `List<>`.

And it is possible to create an implicit conversion operator so that the `Currency cur = "CAD";` syntax works. You can also create another conversion operator so that a Currency gets converted to a String automatically (rather than needing to access the Value property).

```
    public static implicit operator Currency(string name) =>
        new Currency(name);

    public static implicit operator string(Currency currency) =>
        currency.Value;
```

Comment: That is way better than dynamic code generation. Simple and brilliant!