# Reading Data from an Ini File Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, ini

I am reading data from an INI file. INI file look like this

```
[config]
TotalElements=16

#Special Case only elements
ElementNo1=9
ElementNo2=10
ElementNo3=11
ElementNo4=12
#
ElementNo5=2,17
ElementNo6=2,18
ElementNo7=2,19
ElementNo8=2,20
#
ElementNo9=3,17
ElementNo10=3,18
ElementNo11=3,19
ElementNo12=3,20
#
# Special Case only Elements
ElementNo13=9
ElementNo14=10
ElementNo15=11
ElementNo16=12
```

**I am reading the Data from file like this**

```
Dim inifile As New IniFile()
inifile.Load(filePath)
ElementValue = inifile.Sections("config").Keys("TotalElements").Value

For i = 1 To totalElement 
  elementValue = iniSetting.Sections("config").Keys("ElementNo" & i)Value
  ListOfElementNumbers.Add(New ElementMapping With {.ElementNumber = i, .ElementValue = 
  ElementValue, .specialElement = SpecialElement.SpecialElementValue})

Next
```

**Data Structure Look like this**

```
Public Class ElementMapping

Public ElementNumber As Integer
Public ElementValue As Integer
Public specialElement As SpecialElement
End Class

Public Enum SpecialElement
SpecialElementValue
End Enum
```

Now What i want to do is when i am reading the INI file when the Comment **"#Special Case only elements"** Comes from next line until the **"#"** Comes again i want to assign this to Enum in my data structure. And if this comment somewhere in the file again i want to do the same for that special data as well. I am using **"MadMilkman.Ini"** Library to read the data from Ini file.

Comment: Enums cannot be created dynamically, they have to be available at compile time. You can pre-build an assembly, but I am not sure that does what you want. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/automatically-create-an-enum-based-on-values-in-a-database-lookup-table). This link is c# and getting the values from a database, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically create an Enum based on values in a database lookup table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/automatically-create-an-enum-based-on-values-in-a-database-lookup-table)

Comment: @JonathanWillcock no it is not what i am looking for. i already have values in my file and there is certain condition on which i want to assign Enum

Comment: @JonathanWillcock actually what i want is i have some special elements inside my INI file when these special elements comes in the file i want to assign it to the Enum and when these special elements are not in the file everything should be normal

Comment: Maybe create a new INI `Section` for those special elements?

Comment: @HardCode can you post your solution how you are thinking of it?

Comment: @EricTuco you already have a section named `[config]`. Maybe create a section named `[SpecialElements]`?

Comment: @HardCode i don't want to do it hard coded is there anyway like while reading the INI file i read that specific elements and combined them in one section and later read it and assign it to enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Class ElementMapping
    Public ElementNumber As Integer
    Public ElementValue As Integer
    Public SpecialElement As Nullable(Of SpecialElement)
End Class
```

```
Dim iniOptions As New IniOptions() With {.CommentStarter = IniCommentStarter.Hash}
Dim inifile As New IniFile(iniOptions)

' ...

Dim isSpecialCase = False
For i = 1 To totalElement

    Dim iniKey = iniSetting.Sections("config").Keys("ElementNo" & i)
    Dim iniValue = iniKey.Value

    If (String.Equals(iniKey.TrailingComment.Text, String.Empty)) Then
        isSpecialCase = False
    ElseIf (iniKey.TrailingComment.Text?.IndexOf("Special Case only elements", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) Then
        isSpecialCase = True
    End If

    Dim element As New ElementMapping With {.ElementNumber = i, .ElementValue = iniValue}
    If (isSpecialCase) Then element.SpecialElement = SpecialElement.SpecialElementValue
    ListOfElementNumbers.Add(element)

Next
```

In short, I've changed the `ElementMapping.SpecialElement` to a nullable type so that I can differentiate when the element has a special value and when it doesn't.

I'm using `isSpecialCase` to detect if the key is inside the required range. If it is then I'm setting the `ElementMapping.SpecialElement` property to `SpecialElementValue`, otherwise it will be `Nothing`.

For the INI sample you provided, this will result in having your first 4 and last 4 elements with `SpecialElementValue` and the rest will have `Nothing`.

Last, I would suggest that instead of using this nullable type, you consider using something like this:

```
Public Enum SpecialElement
    None,
    SpecialElementValue
End Enum
```

Then instead of `Nothing` you would use `SpecialElement.None`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is some problem in all the iteration i am getting the Enum value as Nothing :(

Comment: The problem is it not going inside the if statement where it is setting isSpecialCase = True. That is why all the values are coming as Nothing

Comment: @EricTuco oh I forgot to mention, you need to use this: `Dim inifile As New IniFile(New IniOptions() With {.CommentStarter = IniCommentStarter.Hash})`

Comment: Great!!! It Works :) Thanks