# Separate big Enum list in different file in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I am facing a problem of scalability with a big Enum file, which has more than 1700 records.

I have to add more records to this Enum, and I am thinking to create a new Enum file to avoid adding more bloat the existing one. This allows as well to separate the Enum type by domain.

The problem is that this does not work, I have to change or duplicate or cast every function that takes this Enum type when I call the function in my new code.

This old Enum file has been created and updated manually overtime, it is not generated from a database. The project has a very very long age (probably 15+ years).

What can be a solution?

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{

    public enum OldBigListDoneBySomeIrresponsiveDev
    {

        [FriendlyName("Unknown")]
        Unknown = 0,
        [FriendlyName("Page1")]
        Page1_Summary = 100000,
        [FriendlyName("Page2")]
        Page2_Summary = 100101,
        [FriendlyName("Page3")]
        Page3_Summary = 100102,
        // .....
        Page1700_Summary = 107102,
    }
}

namespace SomeNameSpace2
{

    public class SomeAttribute: FilterAttribute
    {
        public CheckEnumAttributeAttribute()
        {
            this.Order = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the OldBigListDoneBySomeIrresponsiveDev
        /// </summary>
        public OldBigListDoneBySomeIrresponsiveDev AttrID { get; set; }
    }
}


// attempt to improve
namespace SomeNameSpace
{

    public enum SmallerNicerEnumList
    {

        [FriendlyName("Unknown")]
        Unknown = 0,
        [FriendlyName("Page2000")]
        Page2000_Summary = 100000,
        [FriendlyName("Page2001")]
        Page2001_Summary = 100101,
        [FriendlyName("Page2002")]
        Page2002_Summary = 100102,
    }
}
```

```
// tenative usage of the attribute with new Enum
SomeAttribute(AttrID = SmallerNicerEnumList.Page2000_Summary)
public void SomeController(){}
```

Raises error: Cannot implicity convert type from `SmallerNicerEnumList` to `OldBigListDoneBySomeIrresponsiveDev`

Comment: Why would you have a 100s of items enum? It barely makes sense if auto-generated from a database, but it surely makes no sense if you have to maintain it manually. There must be a better way to do what you are doing.

Comment: have you thought about using sqlite or another database instead

Comment: This is definitely an X/Y problem. Give us some sample pieces of your enum because I would bet a weeks salary that enums are not the correct tool here.

Comment: @nvoigt I am working on a legacy code, I am not sure why this enum kept growing and how it ended up this way. I am looking for ways to improve it without having to refactor half of the project.

Comment: not a bug fan of it but check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/automatically-create-an-enum-based-on-values-in-a-database-lookup-table

Comment: An enum with 1700 members probably means your design is wrong, and by probably I mean 99.999% chance.

Comment: you are not utilizing enum flags, so convert to dictionary (maybe db driven)  and adjust code - would be faster and more reliable.. IMHO

Comment: @ZoharPeled really? I would not had guess that :D. Please do read the question fully, this is a legacy project, I am looking for ways to improve forward not to blame someone and where this design went wrong.

Comment: How many references do you have to this enum? If not too many, it would probably be better to replace with something like a dictionary as suggested in other comments

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot really help if we don't know the specifics. For example why it isn't a database table. Is your app not working with a database? Are these enums actually useful in the code (like if statements based on it, maybe even a 1700 element switch?) or are the just transported through?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 99+ is VS showing, so probably even more

Comment: @nvoigt unfortunately they are used, quite a lot

Comment: One way to solve this issue is by casting. Although it is ugly and not correct, solves the problem of not having to expand the other enum

Comment: I see it as "trivial" to write a "text scanner" that can do something with your "enums" and your source code. "ReadAllLines", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `enum` to a `record` and use the `record` instead, which can be made `partial`, it can also be extended with `implicit` and the like to make it work like an `enum`.

Here is a code example of a console app:

```
Console.WriteLine(BigEnum.Unknown.ToString());
Console.WriteLine((string)BigEnum.Unknown);
Console.WriteLine((int)BigEnum.Unknown);


Console.WriteLine(BigEnum.Page2_Summary.ToString());
Console.WriteLine((string)BigEnum.Page2_Summary);
Console.WriteLine((int)BigEnum.Page2_Summary);

public partial record BigEnum(int Id, string Name)
{
    public static BigEnum Unknown => new(0, "Unknown");
    public static BigEnum Page1_Summary => new(100000, "Page1");

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public static implicit operator int(BigEnum bigEnum) => bigEnum.Id;
    public static implicit operator string(BigEnum bigEnum) => bigEnum.Name;
}

public partial record BigEnum
{
    public static BigEnum Page2_Summary => new(100101, "Page2");
}
```